# Calculating consecutive days

Tags: php

when a user logins into his account I want to calculate since how many consecutive days this user has loged in.

For this I store the a timestamp in `$loginSince` and calculating the consecutive days with this formula:

```
$consecutiveDays = (int)((time() - $loginSince) / DAY) + 1;
```

The problem is that this counts by seconds, meaning:

- if the user logs in at 17:00 (5pm) and on the next day at 15:00 (3pm) the counter is still 1
- if the user logs in at 8:00 (8am) and on the next day at 20:00 (8pm) the counter was resetet (beacause the gap between the two logins is greater than 24h and is again 1

I'd like to get real consectuve days, meaning if a user logs in as the following times:

1. Day 1: 00:01
2. Day 2: 23:59
3. Day 3: 15:00

The counter should say 3, because he loged in at three consectutive days. With my current formular this wont work as the the counter would reset between day 1 and 2.

Can anyone give an advise how to handle this please.

Comment: Store the time stamp as a fixed hour/min/second on that day. e.g. midnight. Then the maths will work.

Comment: Whenerver the user logs in increase the counter. and in check condition  just check, counter should be `greater than or equal` to the no of difference between first and last day(Assume this day as the user is currently log n now). For this you may have store `one variable` for first day . The difference is no of days

Comment: @EdHeal My solution is based on your Idea. I created two `DateTime`s of Midnight at these days and build the `interval` of them. Thank you. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it to show others what was helpful for me?

Comment: @bish - Why not post your own solution and accept that? I would need to write some PHP and test - but I do not have a PHP interpreter to hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post the solution I made. It's based on the idea of *Ed Heal* to always compare fixed times. I had chosen midnight. After that I build the `interval` of this to also handle year changes and streaks for more than a year

```
$loginSince = $this->dailyLoginSince($account);

// Create midnight date of the moment the login-streak started
$loginSinceMidnight = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$loginSince).' 00:00:00');

// We create the difference between the two dates, both at midnight
$numericDayLoginSince = new DateTime();
$numericDayLoginSince->setTimestamp($loginSinceMidnight);

$numericDayNow = new DateTime();
$timestamp = strtotime('today midnight');
$numericDayNow->setTimestamp($timestamp);

$interval = $numericDayLoginSince->diff($numericDayNow);
$loginSinceDays = $interval->format('%a'); // %a = Number of days

// +1 because it seems to be more thrilling, that we already got one day
// by just logging in for the first time.

return $loginSinceDays + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use [date('z')](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), as that should just give you the day and not the time?

Comment: I like the idea but as it returns `0 through 365` whats with 29. feb? whats with the change from 31.12 to 01.01  as `365 + 1 != 0`

Comment: Ok the above I could handle, but how to handle a streak from more than a year?